# Entity Framework performance vs Traditional ADO.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, query-performance

To show my question I try to explain a sample:

Suppose that I have a table `UsersInfo` with these columns:

```
Id, UserName, Password, FName, LName, Gender, Birthday, 
HomeTel, Mobile, Fax, Email, LockStatus
```

Now I want to select `LockStatus` from this table. In traditional mode we made this query and send it to `SqlCommand` for execute:

```
SELECT LockStatus FROM UsersInfo
```

And today with use Entity Framework, we use this from of query:

```
var q = from r in new Data_DBEntities().UsersInfo
        select new
        {
           r.LockStatus
        };
```

Entity SQL:

```
SELECT UsersInfo.LockStatus
FROM Data_DBEntities.UsersInfo
```

Now I start the application and trace this it with SQL Server Profiler. If I use the first type of query (traditional mode) I see this result:

```
SELECT LockStatus FROM UsersInfo
```

But when I use Entity Framework (LINQ || Entity SQL) the SQL Server Profiler show this result:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[LockStatus] AS [LockStatus]
FROM (SELECT 
      [UsersInfo].[Id] AS [Id], 
      [UsersInfo].[UserName] AS [UserName],
      [UsersInfo].[Password] AS [Password],
      [UsersInfo].[FName] AS [FName],
      [UsersInfo].[LName] AS [LName],
      [UsersInfo].[Gender] AS [Gender],
      [UsersInfo].[Birthday] AS [Birthday],
      [UsersInfo].[HomeTel] AS [HomeTel],
      [UsersInfo].[Mobile] AS [Mobile],
      [UsersInfo].[Fax] AS [Fax],
      [UsersInfo].[Email] AS [Email],
      [UsersInfo].[LockStatus] AS [LockStatus]
      FROM [dbo].[UsersInfo] AS [UsersInfo]) AS [Extent1]
```

We can see that EF in the background select all of columns.

Now my question is: I just want to select one column, but EF selects all of the columns. If I had 100,000 records in my table, the performance would be really bad!

Maybe say use function or stored procedure, but when you want select different columns in different tables, that's not a good idea.

What do you think? Is there any way?

Comment: You do something wrong. EF will query all fields to generate the objects - obviously. But if you do make a proejction in the query then it will not. THat said - this is where my help ends because I am not familiar with the LINQ sql syntax, preferring functional syntax for myself. I definitely do not have this problem.

Comment: Whilst I understand that the query looks heavy, I find EF (now at v6) to be equally as fast as traditional ADO.NET and I have tables with 10's of millions of rows - providing the query is correctly written.  If you're concerned **about performance**, have you considered running tests **on the performance**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that EF generated has a redundant derived table in it but ultimately it only selects one column. SQL Server, and probably any mainstream RDBMS, only physically touches a single column in this case. Don't worry about performance. This is just cosmetics.

You have done nothing wrong. There's nothing to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used in your LINQ query forced the duplicate selects.

Your projection created 2 separate objects.

`var q = from r in new Data_DBEntities().UsersInfo` created a new object, and then the

```
    select new
    {
       r.LockStatus
    };
```

created a new object based on the first one.  You do not need the `new` keyword in your first section.

if you change the query to be:

```
var q = from r in Data_DBEntities().UsersInfo
    select new
    {
       r.LockStatus
    };
```

you will get an anonymous projection without an additional object. (And without the additional fields to base the extent on.)

Comment: @Jourmand: ***WHAT*** error!?!?!? Remember: we **cannot** read your screen, nor your mind!

Comment: my Orginal code is:

`var d = new Data_DBEntities();
var q = from r in d.UsersInfo
        select new
        {
           r.LockStatus
        };`
But my problem is: why EF SELECT All of the fields, is it normal or not? I used LINQ and then try Entity SQL, but in tow way I See the same result.

Comment: @Jourmand - EF is *NOT* selecting all the fields.  You need ot look at the SQL more carefully.  It's doing a subselect and only selecting a single field.

Comment: @AndrewCounts - That's not going to work, since a data context cannot be used statically like that.

Comment: the problem here is not that he's trying to use new to get a new data context, the problem here is that he's not getting a new data context, he's getting a new UsersInfo object and doing a subselect from that.  if the data context doesn't already exist, he needs to new it before this statement or wrap it in a using, but this code doesn't show anything to indicate how he derives the Data Context.  the original statement is still valid, the subselect is caused by multiple new keywords in the query.